# How to get the table row index based on value in a particular column

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Fairly simple question: I want to get the row index of the table based on value in a particular column. Lets say the column name is "ID", it has unique values in my TableView.

Now, I want to retrieve the row index where the column "ID" is 22.

I only have access to the TableView object and the column("ID") value with me.

Comment: You can search the Observable list object like -> for(int i = 0; i < obvList.length; i++){if(obvList.get(i).getID() == 22) {index = i;}}

Answer (score 2):

Use this code.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < tableView.getItems().size(); i++) {
        if (tableView.getItems().get(i).getId() == 22) {
            System.out.println("Selected Index : "+i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Although tableView.getItems().get(i).getId() will not work but I get the row array using tableView.getItems().get(i) which I can use to get the value as I know the column index. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to select row using mouse. Than you can try something like this

```
tableview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()
```

Comment: not need to repeat an answer, particularly so it that answer is ... unrelated to the question ..